# What would be the time complexity of this and why?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

What would be the time complexity of the method below and why?

I know it must be greater than O(n) because of the first for loop.

But what happens to the time complexity after the while loop?

Is it O(n)(n-1) = O(n^2 + n)?

```
int fnA(int n) {
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int j=i;
        int product =1;
        while (j>1) {
            product ∗= j ;
            j = j / 2;
        }
        sum += product;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. What have you tried? The complexity is polynomial here, and larger than `O(n)`. By the way, `O(n^2 + n)` does not make much sense, since asymptotically, `n^2` dominates, so what you want to write in that case is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @William yeah it's an exam question that I'm prepping for. So it's O(n^2 + n) and I'm right? :)

Comment: Well, you're on the right track, but see my edit to the comment above.

Comment: @William Ah yeah you're right, the final answer is O(n^2) because you're meant to take the biggest one right?

Comment: This should get you on the right track: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/228744/258990

Comment: @Naomi Yes. Well, technically, asymptotically the largest.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like `O(n log n)` to me.  The main loop iterates `n` times, and each iteration takes `log n` additional iterations to complete, since `j` starts at `i` and is halved until `j <= 1`. If you imagine the total time for all the iterations of the inner loop, you get the following sum.

```
O(0 log n) + O(1 log(n-1)) + ... + O(n/2 log (n/2)) + ... + O((n-2) log 2) + O((n-1) log 1) =
O(log n) + O(n log n) + O(n) =
O(n log n)
```